# Integrate the following trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem given is as follows:-
$$\int {{(\cos2x)(\sin4x)}\over{(\cos x)^4(1+(\cos 2x)^2)}}$$

In the first step, I expanded $\sin4x$ to get:-

$\int{{(\cos2x)(2\sin2x\cos2x)}\over{(\cos x)^4(1+(\cos2x)^2)}}=\int{{(\cos2x)^2(2\sin2x)}\over{(\cos x)^4(1+(\cos2x)^2)}}$

So to convert the $\cos^4x$ term in the denominator, I tried the following:-

$(\cos2x)^2=(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)^2=(2\cos^2x-1)^2=4\cos^4x+1-\cos^2x$

Only to realise that it would further complicate the integral

Another method i thought of was taking $\cos2x=t$ as a substitution, but there is an annoying $\cos^4x$ term in the denominator which has me worried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're integrating with respect to $x.$

If so, then take notice that the $\cos(2x)$ in the denominator has the derivative $-4\cos(2x)\sin(2x).$ This is almost the numerator, so take $y=\cos (2x),$ to get the $$-\int{\frac{y^2 \mathrm d y}{\left({\frac{1+y}{2}}\right)^2(1+y)}}=-4\int {\frac{y^2 \mathrm d y}{(1+y)^3}}.$$

Now let $1+y=g,$ to get $$-\int{\frac{(g-1)^2\mathrm d g}{g^3}}=-4\int{\left(1-\frac 1g\right)^2\frac 1g \mathrm d g}.$$ Finally, letting $1/g =z,$ we obtain the $$-4\int{\frac{(1-z)^2z\mathrm d z}{-z^2}}=4\int{\frac{(1-z)^2}{z}\mathrm d z}=4\int{(1/z-2+z)\mathrm d z},$$ from where you should be able to continue.

Answer (score 0):

HInt:

$$\dfrac{\cos2x\sin4x}{\cos^4x(1+\cos2x)^2}=4\cdot\dfrac{\cos2x\cdot2\cos2x\sin2x}{(2\cos^2x)^2(1+\cos2x)^2}=\dfrac{8\cos^22x\sin2x}{(1+\cos2x)^4}$$

Set $1+\cos2x=y$